# jQuery - scroll to next sibling with specific class

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Good day!
I want a button that when you click it, the window will scroll to element with specific class.

I have this snippet. It scrolls, but when the next sibling should be skipped, it doesn't scroll.

Also, if it's possible. When it reaches the last element, the 'current' should go back to the top.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

```js
     $('#nextBtn').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
     
       if ($('#nextBtn') && $('.current').next('li.scroll').length > 0) {
           
           var $next = $('.current').next('.scroll');
           var top = $next.offset().top;
           
           $('.current').removeClass('current');
         
           $('body').animate({
             scrollTop: top     
           }, function () {
                  $next.addClass('current');
           });
         }
      
     });
```

```css
#nextBtn {position:fixed;top:0;right:50px;text-align:right;}
li{color:white;background: #333;margin:10px 0;height:500px;list-style:none;padding:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="nextBtn">NEXT</button>

<li class="scroll current">Scroll here!</li>
<li class="scroll">Scroll here!</li>
<li class="scroll">Scroll here!</li>
<li class="not-scroll">DO NOT scroll here!</li>
<li class="not-scroll">DO NOT scroll here!</li>
<li class="scroll">Scroll here!</li>
<li class="scroll last">Scroll here!</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` selects only the immediate sibling, then checks whether it satisfies the selector if does not match then it doesn't return anything. It doesn't select the next sibling matching the selector.

One easy solution is to find all the next siblings matching the selector, then take the first one like

```
var $next = $('.current').nextAll('.scroll').first();
```

```js
$('#nextBtn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $current = $('.current'),
    $next = $current.nextAll('.scroll').first();
  if (!$next.length) {
    $next = $('.scroll').first();
  }

  if ($next.length) {


    var $next = $next.first();
    var top = $next.offset().top;

    $current.removeClass('current');

    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, function() {
      $next.addClass('current');
    });
  }

});
```

```css
#nextBtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 500px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="nextBtn">NEXT</button>

<ul>
  <li class="scroll current">Scroll here 1!</li>
  <li class="scroll">Scroll here 2!</li>
  <li class="scroll">Scroll here 3!</li>
  <li class="not-scroll">DO NOT scroll here!</li>
  <li class="not-scroll">DO NOT scroll here!</li>
  <li class="scroll">Scroll here 4!</li>
  <li class="scroll last">Scroll here 5!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Arun, this one works. thanks for the enlighten. I have another problem. If the 'current' class reached the last element, how can I bring it back to the top?

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! Edit: will accept your answer after 5mins